# How to insert TextView in Activity from other non activity class Android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to set `TextView` object of `Main3Activity` (Activity class) from `IncomingSms` (Non activity class).

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRE DETECTED")) {
                        //Problem start here: I cant able to set TextView object of Main3Activity
                        Main3Activity main3Activity = new Main3Activity();
                        TextView tv = (TextView) main3Activity.findViewById(R.id.firealert);
                        tv.setText(message);
                        //Problem end here
                        Log.i("SmsReceived", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make inner brodcast receiver, then you can set text easily

Comment: did you got your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an interface class save it as java class then

```
public interface SmsListener {
            public void messageReceived(String messageText);
    }
```

and

```
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
private static SmsListener mListener;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String senderNum = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRE DETECTED") ){
                    mListener.messageReceived(message); //add this
                    Log.i("SmsReceived", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
    }
}
public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

And in your `Main3Activity` onCreate method

```
TextView tv=(TextView) main3Activity.findViewById(R.id.firealert);


SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
                @Override
                public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
                    Log.d("Text",messageText);
                     tv.setText(messageText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: @SowmithraKumara glad to hear that but please mark it as answer

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, I voted up, but it showing after earning 15 reputation, Vote will be applied!

Comment: @SowmithraKumara I not talking about voting. you can mark it as answer by clicking the green tick found left of my answer

Comment: @SowmithraKumara after accepting my answer you will get that permission too

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the activity instance like that.

Solution:
1. Create a broadcast receiver in your activity and register for a custom intent.
2. Send a custom broadcast intent from your sms receiver. So basically that will reach activity receiver and then you can simply update the text there.

In case your activity is not started, simply create a activity intent and pass the sms text as part of the intent extras.